# Define an event as true or false in a datalayer

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am using a widget on my website. Its function: the user clicks on it and can select a different font for the page is seeing. He can also decide to reset to the default setting.

I want to measure the users that click & select a different point and end their session with this new setting.

```
window.dataLayer.push({
                      "event": "font-change",
"action": "click",
"label": "size 15", });
```

What I want to do is to segment the users font-change users vs the rest.

So my question is: what do I need to add in my datalayer to measure that my event is "on" (so the user has clicked on my wiidget and select a new font) or the event is off (the user did not click at all or has has clicked but afterwards reset to the default settings.

I hope it's clear :)

I could not find any information on the web, so I did not try anything

Comment: 1. You might need to store the original setting in some place like localStorage. 2. detect what the user choose and compare to the original setting. 3. If these two are different then you know the user choose the new font setting and push datalayer about what you need to measure